# org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9 using WITH in Query

Tags: hibernate-mapping, nativequery

In my Native-Query, I got this following exception:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9
```

Can someone explain me, what that problem describes?

Here is my Native-Query for MSSQL, which I tried:

```
WITH ALLE_MONATE AS (
    SELECT 1 AS MONAT
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MONAT + 1
    FROM ALLE_MONATE
    WHERE MONAT < 12
)

SELECT
    ISNULL(COUNT(V_GI_AGENDA_KONSULTATION.VON), 0) AS COUNT,
    DATENAME(MONTH, CAST('2023-' + CAST(ALLE_MONATE.MONAT AS VARCHAR) + '-01' AS DATE)) AS GROUPING,
    'Agenda Konsultation' AS SERIE
FROM ALLE_MONATE
         LEFT JOIN V_GI_AGENDA_KONSULTATION ON ALLE_MONATE.MONAT = MONTH(V_GI_AGENDA_KONSULTATION.VON) AND YEAR(V_GI_AGENDA_KONSULTATION.VON) = 2023 AND V_GI_AGENDA_KONSULTATION.ID_FIRMA = :ID_FIRMA
GROUP BY ALLE_MONATE.MONAT
```

It seems like the problem is about the WITH-Syntax. So I heard, Native can execute only one query.
An normal Query like `SELECT * FROM TABLE_XX` works for me.
Thanks in advance.